# Listening on multiple Azure Service Bus queues (dynamic list)

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azureservicebus

I am trying to create listener in Spring Boot which will listen on many queues in Azure Service Bus. The idea is that the listener has to search for all queues that meet the naming convention (for example: `queue-{userId}-name`) and expect messages on each of them.

It would be a great advantage that the listener will be able to detect for which userId (from queue name) the message was coming in.

Unfortunately I don't have any code that solved event te small part of my problem. I am experienced in working with Spring boot and queues, but this is the first time I have experienced this problem

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring Boot but would assume it has a way to use something like a management client (available in .NET SDK) to enumerate the entities. Saying that I'm not entirely sure I get the design. If you have a system that has more than 10,000 users you will quickly run out of queues available for a single namespace.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do right now.
1) Use management client to list all queues
2) Filter all with name matching the pattern
3) Create a listener for each queue and assign to `userId`